# Rails throws "REXML::ParseException does not have a valid root" exception

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a JavaScript object, and converted it into JSON using [Douglas Crockford's JSON utility](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). While sending a post AJAX request, I get:

> REXML::ParseException does not have a valid root

```
REXML::ParseException (The document "{\"name\":\"asda\",\"deadline\":\"May 24, 2011\"}" does not have a valid root):
```

I am not able to proceed with this error.

Answer (score 9):

When making your AJAX request, you're probably sending the wrong Content-Type header. If you make a request with the header `Content-Type: application/xml`, Rails will try to parse your request body as XML, and you'll get that error message. Instead, you'll want to use `application/json` or another content-type so that Rails won't try to parse it. If you're using jQuery, this is the `contentType` setting in [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: This might also happen when you do not specify a content type at all. Rails will try to interpret your post as XML by default.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't require there to be a root element the way XML does.  Try parsing it with JSON.parse(json_string), instead of with REXML.

Answer (score -1):

See the below mentioned json file

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here glossary is the root element which encloses the whole json similarly to xml as displayed below.

```
<!DOCTYPE glossary PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V3.1//EN">
 <glossary><title>example glossary</title>
  <GlossDiv><title>S</title>
   <GlossList>
    <GlossEntry ID="SGML" SortAs="SGML">
     <GlossTerm>Standard Generalized Markup Language</GlossTerm>
     <Acronym>SGML</Acronym>
     <Abbrev>ISO 8879:1986</Abbrev>
     <GlossDef>
      <para>A meta-markup language, used to create markup
languages such as DocBook.</para>
      <GlossSeeAlso OtherTerm="GML">
      <GlossSeeAlso OtherTerm="XML">
     </GlossDef>
     <GlossSee OtherTerm="markup">
    </GlossEntry>
   </GlossList>
  </GlossDiv>
 </glossary>
```

Hence we can say that the glossary is the root and is only one tag in xml or json.

Hence you have to provide a root element in the json file which encloses the whole JSON file.