# HttpRequest.setRequestHeader generates DOM Exception 11 on Dart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, httprequest, dart

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/) in order to run a POST method from dart to my ruby on rails back-end application. So, in the first time I tried the code as the tutorial shows, just changing my URL and the JSON data.

```dart
void main() {   
  String jsonData = '{"color":"blue","x":"100","y":"100"}'; 
  saveData(jsonData, onSuccess); // send the data to  // the server
}

void onSuccess(HttpRequest req) {
    print(req.responseText); // print the received raw JSON text
}

void saveData(String data, onSuccess(HttpRequest req)) {
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR

  // add an event handler that is called when the request finishes
  req.on.readyStateChange.add((Event e) {
    if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
        (req.status == 200 || req.status == 0)) {
      onSuccess(req); // called when the POST successfully completes
    }
  });

  var url = "http://localhost:3030/colored_rectangles.json";
  req.open("POST", url); // Use POST http method to send data in the next call
  req.send(data); // kick off the request to the server

}
```

Here's the method in my controller and my model in ruby (very simple, generated with scaffold):

```rb
  # POST /colored_rectangles
  # POST /colored_rectangles.json
  def create
    @colored_rectangle = ColoredRectangle.new(params[:colored_rectangle])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @colored_rectangle.save
        format.html { redirect_to @colored_rectangle, notice: 'Colored rectangle was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @colored_rectangle, status: :created, location: @colored_rectangle }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @colored_rectangle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

```rb
class ColoredRectangle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :color, :x, :y
end
```

When I run the code, I receive the following error in Dart:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
  http://localhost:3030/colored_rectangles.json
```

And the log in Rails:

```
REXML::ParseException (The document "{\"color\":\"blue\",\"x\":\"100\",\"y\":\"100\"}" does not have a valid root):
 activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/xml_mini/rexml.rb:35:in `parse'
 C:in `parse'
  etc....
```

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106556/rails-throws-rexmlparseexception-does-not-have-a-valid-root-exception), I tried to change the header to "Content-Type: application/json", then I tried to call the [overriedMimeType method](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/HttpRequest.html#overrideMimeType) but it gives me the same error.

```dart
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
```

I also called the [setRequestHeader method](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/HttpRequest.html#setRequestHeader), with the following code:

```dart
void saveLanguageData(String data, onSuccess(HttpRequest req)) {
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR

  // add an event handler that is called when the request finishes
  req.on.readyStateChange.add((Event e) {
    if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
        (req.status == 200 || req.status == 0)) {
      onSuccess(req); // called when the POST successfully completes
    }
  });

  var url = "http://localhost:3030/colored_rectangles.json";
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); //This was added
  req.open("POST", url); // Use POST http method to send data in the next call
  req.send(data); // kick off the request to the server

}
```

But I receive the following error from Dart:

```
Exception: Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
Stack Trace: #0      HttpRequest.setRequestHeader (E:\b\build\slave\dartium-win-full-trunk\build\src\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\webkit\bindings\dart\dart\html\HttpRequest.dart:34:1)
#1      saveLanguageData (http://localhost:3030/rademo_dart/web/rademo.dart:45:23)
#2      main (http://localhost:3030/rademo_dart/web/rademo.dart:10:19)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh well, I found the answer to my problem... Actually the setRequestHeader needs to be called after the req.open, so the saveData method code will be the following:

```dart
void saveData(String data, onSuccess(HttpRequest req)) {
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR

  // add an event handler that is called when the request finishes
  req.on.readyStateChange.add((Event e) {
    if (req.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
        (req.status == 200 || req.status == 0)) {
      onSuccess(req); // called when the POST successfully completes
    }
  });

  var url = "http://localhost:3030/colored_rectangles.json";
  req.open("POST", url); // Use POST http method to send data in the next call
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  req.send(data); // kick off the request to the server

}
```

Comment: Yeah, the standard XMLHttpRequest isn't exactly easy to use. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

On `@colored_rectangle = ColoredRectangle.new(params[:colored_rectangle])`, in your `create` method, you're sending the data to the constructor of ColoredRectangle, but you're doing it by using the root `:colored_rectangle`. This root is not present in the json you sent. To fix it, just add the root to the json, like this: `String jsonData = '{"colored_rectangle": {"color":"blue","x":"100","y":"100"}}';`

Comment: Even if I change the jsonData variable to contain the header, it does not work. But it does work if I add the `req.setRequestHeader` after the open method.